# Random license plate generator

Tags: python

There is random license plate generator. It generates license plates with 3 letters and 3 numbers but it excludes letters Q, W and X in all three letter positions, and 000 in number position. I tried to code this on Python but it showed an error message:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

```
The code is this:
import random as o
r=o.randint
t,j,k=[],0,""
b=["Q", "W", "X", "000"]
for i in range(100):
 l,j=b[0],b[4]
 while any(w in l for w in b):
  l,j="",""
  for i in range(3):
   l+=chr(r(65,90))
   j+=str(r(0,9))
 t.append(l+'-'+j)
print ("\n".join(set(t)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l,j=b[0],b[4]
```

Here you're getting index `4` but you're only using length of `4`, so the last item has index `3`, change it to:

```
l,j=b[0],b[3]
```

---

##### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/BasMwDIbvegqhS22iBY@wQQd@iJ02SHNI1myx59rGMZQ@fVrl2MuP@Pj0C@VbXVLsts1dcioVyxjP6YLjigmg2NQKcLECVPb8b/uBDRMBTLanT2KkL4lvCWMMDQC/qaBDF6Xrb1avxugPwMDeTr0ZeOq7AfC6uDDjGG/qKmpA2drHSexdJ5JLiE@F3S5gaOzPUlRR7298NFoL841dqzDDRyG1HXOe41mF5vByaLyGXB7PoKJTpNYnF9U6V1W11tt2Bw)

Output:

```
MLD-767
SMP-526
PIR-280
JBY-473
MRZ-876
VEN-206
FNI-643
ULH-631
ZCK-707
...
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. Here's another one:

```
from random import choices, randint

LETTERS = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUVYZ'

def gen_number_plate():
    letters = ''.join(choices(LETTERS, k=3))
    numbers = randint(1, 999)
    return f'{letters}-{numbers:03d}'

print(gen_number_plate())
```